# Coverting watts to kWh in python by multiplying and dividing lists

Tags: python, list

The formula: `kWh = hourlylist * wattlist/1000`

my two lists:

```
wattlist = [3500.0, 250.0, 2150.0, 2000.0, 60.0, 2790.0, 350.0, 80.0, 75.0, 1800.0] #each index #represents a different device in watt(10 devices)

hourlylist = [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.075, 0.075, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]] #each of the smaller #list represents each devives hourly usuage over 12 hours (10 smaller list within 1 big list)
```

how should my code look if I want my ouput to still stay in my hourly list format but after I #used my formula that calculated kWh

I tried:

```
for i in range (len(hourlylist)):
    for j in range(len(hourlylist[i])):
        for k in range(len(wattlist)):
            hourlylist[i][j] = float(hourlylist[i][j]) * wattlist[k]/1000
print(hourlylist)
```

but it gave me:

The calculations doesnt add up...

Comment: You seems to have accounted for the `k` in your formular. Now you also need to account for the `h`.

Comment: Your code is correct. Why do you think that the calculation "doesn't add up"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think wattlist should be traversed first. Then one watt(device) map an hourly. Try code below:

```
for i, watt in enumerate(wattlist):
    # each watt map an hourly
    hourly = hourlylist[i]
    for j, hour in enumerate(hourly):
        hourly[j] = float(hour * watt) / 1000
print(hourlylist)
```

The result looks like:

```
[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.15, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06], [0.0, 1.395, 1.395, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.0, 0.08, 0.08], [0.075, 0.075, 0.075, 0.075, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.075, 0.075, 0.075, 0.075], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.135, 0.135, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```